# How to self-define likelihood with dmulti() in JAGS?

Tags: bayesian, multinomial-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

I am running a hierarchical Bayesian model and would like to use the "ones trick" to self-define a likelihood function, just to prevent the problems that **dmulti()** may have with zeros. To be able to use the "ones trick", I would first need to specify the pmf for multinomial distribution.

In this [post](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/09321754/), Martyn Plummer mentioned that we can actually get the likelihood of the Gamma distribution by using **dgamma()** directly, e.g.:

```
logGamma[i] <- log(dgamma(y[i], shape[i], rate[i]))
```

Based on above, I assumed it applies to other distribution functions too and wrote below code:

```
LikMulti[i,k]<- dmulti(y.comp[i,2:5,k],comp.p[i,1:4,k],y.comp[i,6,k])
```

where both *y.comp[i,2:5,k]* and *y.comp[i,6,k]* are both observations, and *comp.p[i,1:4,k]* is the expected population composition obtained from the process model.

However, when I run this, I obtained an error message like this:

```
 Error in jags.model("test.R", data = data, inits = inits, n.chains = length(inits),  : 
  RUNTIME ERROR:
 Compilation error on line 186.
 Unknown function: dmulti
```

And my questions are:

1. I wonder has anyone met the same error? As the **dmulti()** should be the right function to use for multinomial distribution, I wonder does this mean I cannot obtain likelihood of multinomial distribution from **dmulti()** directly?
2. If I cannot obtain likelihood directly with **dmulti()**, I wonder is there any function that can help me put down the pmf of multinomial distribution in JAGS, as the pmf is quite a complicated one?

Comment: The correct syntax for dmulti has only two parameters based on JAGS 4.0 [manual](http://www.uvm.edu/~bbeckage/Teaching/DataAnalysis/Manuals/manual.jags.pdf): pi and n, where pi is a vector of probabilities and n is the number of trials.

Comment: Hi, Marcio, thanks for the reply! Yes I understand that usually the likelihood is specified by  y.comp[i,2:5,k] ~ dmulti(comp.p[i,1:4,k],y.comp[i,6,k]). However, in order to  self-define a likelihood function by using the "ones trick", i.e. specifying a new sampling distribution that JAGS doesn't have such as zero-inflated distribution, I have to specify the likelihood functions I'd like to contain in the mixture distribution individually by using "<-" and sum them all.

Comment: This part isn't included in the JAGS manual, but from the response by Martyn Plummer to post I mentioned above, it seems that the likelihood can be specified directly by using dgamma(y[i], shape[i], rate[i]), just like in R. From the discussion in the post, it seems to work well for dgamma, but it returns an error I don't understand when I applies it to dmulti. This raises my questions.

Comment: Based on Plummer's post, I am not sure if dgamma function is the same as the Gamma distribution function which also is also called by dgamma. Notice that he points out that the dgamma function follows the same syntax of the Gamma distribution function.

Anyway, writing the likelihood of the multinomial distribution is not so hard in your case. Just ignore the constant:
`LikMulti[i,k] <-  (y.comp[i,2,k]^comp.p[i,1,k])*(y.comp[i,3,k]^comp.p[i,2,k])*(y.comp[i,4,k]^comp.p[i,3,k])*(y.comp[i,5,k]^comp.p[i,4,k])`

Comment: Thanks for the idea about putting down the pmf directly. I just came across [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62418/binomial-coefficient-in-jags) today and found that there is actually an function that helps us putting down factorial in JAGS. This should be helpful. But I was still curious about why we can ignore the coefficient term?

Comment: Your posterior distribution is given by $p(\theta|\mathbf{y}) = \displaystyle\frac{f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)p(\theta)}{f(\mathbf{y})}$, where $\theta$ is the parameter of interest, $\mathbf{y}$ is the vector of observations, $p(\theta)$ is the prior distribution, $f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)$ is the likelihood, and $f(\mathbf{y})$ is the marginal distribution of your observations.

Comment: When you present your posterior as $p(\theta|\mathbf{y}) = \displaystyle\frac{f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)p(\theta)}{f(\mathbf{y})}$, you have that $\int \displaystyle\frac{f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)p(\theta)}{f(\mathbf{y})} d\theta = 1$ as expected since $p(\theta|\mathbf{y})$ is a distribution of probability.

Comment: However, you also can write your posterior as $p(\theta|\mathbf{y}) \propto f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)p(\theta)$. Notice that we ignored $f(\mathbf{y})$ because the denominator is constant in relation to $\theta$.

Comment: We can do that because we know that $p(\theta|\mathbf{y})$ is a distribution of probability, i.e., $\int p(\theta|\mathbf{y})d\theta = 1$. Thus, we just need to integrate $\int f(\mathbf{y}|\theta)p(\theta) d\theta = f(\mathbf{y})$ then we will recover the constant that makes the integral being equal to 1.

Comment: As we ignored $f(\mathbf{y})$, we also can ignore any constant terms in relation to θθ of the likelihood $f(\mathbf{y}|θ)$. Notice that you do not define the marginal distribution $f(\mathbf{y})$ in JAGS, but you define the likelihood and the prior distribution. It is because $f(\mathbf{y})$ is constant in relation to $\theta$.